# Oracle Sequence not generating the continuous number

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sequence

I have one sequence in oracle which will be used as SYSID. The sequence is not generating in orderly fashion, means some where it is skipping the numbers, then it is continuing.

Below is my sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE leaveform_seq 
MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 
INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1560
CACHE 20 ORDER NOCYCLE;
```

Any Alternative for Sequence?

Answer (score 8):

An Oracle sequence is generator for a *guaranteed* series of *unique* numbers which performs well and scales in a multi-user environment.  The trade off for performance and scalability is that occasionally there are gaps in the series.

It is incredibly rare to find a use case where such gaps really matter to the organisation.  Although it is tragically all too common for people to get into a needless frenzy about them.

---

Are there alternatives to sequences?  Sure, we're always free to write our own code.  Depending on your business needs it might be quite simple or it might be rather complicated.

The important things to bear in mind to bear in mind are performance and scalability.  You are inevitably sacrificing a bit of both by choosing not to use a sequence.  But writing your own series generator provides an opportunity to really muck things up.

So, understand the implications and be sure your boss is fully sold on the idea.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is how they work. Sequences are not guaranteed to give a gapless list of numbers, partly because a rollback of a transaction that used a sequence value does not return the value to the available list, and partly because of sequence caching.

That should not be a problem for a non-meaningful id.

There is a long discussion of this here: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:530735152441

Answer (score 0):

if you set `CACHE 1` instead of `CACHE 20`  you will  have less gaps

Comment: But still not guaranteed gap-free, with the added disadvantage of potentially worse performance.

Comment: Every call to NEXTVAL will write to the data dictionary.  So I would say guaranteed worse performance.  Although perhaps not *noticeably* worse, depending on how much the sequence is used.

Comment: yea, but it's often a trade off between performance an desired  functionality

Comment: any alternative for Sequence?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean NOCACHE?  And even with NOCACHE you can still have gaps due to rollbacks.  Simply put, there is NO WAY (that I know of, and I failed KnowingEverything 101 :-) to guarantee a gap-free list of numbers from a sequence.  A sequence will guarantee a monotonically increasing set of numbers, but can't guarantee they'll be gap-free.

Comment: @BobJarvis: agreed; but it's even worse in the presence of RAC: a sequence will only guarantee uniqueness, but is not guaranteed to generate numbers in a nice monotonically ascending order :)