# Primary keys generated by sequencegenerator are written into database incorrectly

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, persistence

I noticed a strange problem happening with the application I am writing.

I use Hibernate, Spring and Oracle database. There is a Orders table in the database, which has its PK generated by a sequence. I defined this in the application as follows:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_ORDER_ID")
@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_ORDER_ID", sequenceName="SEQ_ORDER_ID", allocationSize=1)
@Column(name = "ID_ORDER", length = 10, nullable = false)
```

For saving the Order into database, I create a new Order `Order order = new Order();`, set its values and use `session.persist(order).`

Now, the Order object has the correct primary key generated, let's say `120`, while previous one was `119`, but when I look into the database, the newly created order row has primary key value `121`. I used debug and went through the process of creating the Order, that is how I got these values.

If I try creating a new order directly in sqldeveloper, the sequence works correctly and values increment by one.

This happens with every insert, not just Order. The primary key value written into database is consistently +2 instead of +1.

All of the Oracle sequences have the `INCREMENT_BY` value `1`.

I tried adding `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();` after the persist, but nothing changes.

Has anyone ever experienced this? Do You have any idea what I might be doing wrong here that causes this behavior?

Comment: Are you asking why Oracle does not generates sequence increment_by 1? if so, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165954/oracle-sequence-not-generating-the-continuous-number.

Comment: I am trying to figure out what happens after I save the value with `persist`. I can see that the `Order` object gets the correct primary key value, but to the database is saved incorrect value (the correct value +1).

Comment: Have you enabled sql logging to make sure that the application is not generating extra sequence values? Sequences shouldn't magically skip values

Comment: I don't think I have, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: how do you use sqldeveloper? I doubt you are using triggers to always assign a new sequence value. in this case Spring will generate one number and the trigger will take the next.

Comment: I am using triggers to assign the next sequence value on new row creation. Is that wrong?

Comment: It is not wrong, but this is the reason for your question as Isalamon wrote.

Comment: I may have found the answer in another question here, I will look into it when I can. Thank you all so much for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for pointing me in the right direction!

The issue was in the triggers in my database generating new ID even though one was sent from the application. I had to add `WHEN (NEW.ID_ORDER is NULL)` before the trigger's `BEGIN` to fix this issue.

As per this answer: [HIbernate issue with Oracle Trigger for generating id from a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002119/hibernate-issue-with-oracle-trigger-for-generating-id-from-a-sequence)